# How to split string by \ in c#

Tags: c#, string

I know how to split  string. For example.

```
 var str = line.Split(',')[1];
```

Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Müllabfuhr", "Müllabfuhr\Müllabfuhr.csproj", "{1909EBCB-DDDF-469E-9F84-0B0A3B86A861}"

String i used to split.

I want to do the same but now split at "\" . I treid to just insert "\" instead of ",", but i doesnt seem to work.

"C:\Users\lennartf\Desktop\Unbenannt.png"

Comment: A backslash like any escaped character starts with \, so write \\

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `var str = @"C:\Users\lennartf\Desktop\Unbenannt.png".Split('\\');`